# Collect with symbolic exponents does not simplify any further

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic

I am trying to simplify a symbolic expression. Here is an example:

```
f1[x_] := (2/x) (c/x)^(\[Gamma] - 1);
f2[x_] := 1 - 2/x (1 + f1[x] + f1[x]^(-\[Theta]))
Collect[f2[x], x^_]
```

The result is this:

[image]

But this can still be further simplified, for example: in the second term on the fraction, the exponents gamma and theta are not combined, and the x in the denominator is also ignored. How can I automate a further simplification?

Comment: Please update the post with the desired result as expressions can take many forms. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You need to apply some appropriate assumptions, and force `FullSimplify` into preferring fewer `x`s:

```
Collect[
  FullSimplify[
    #,
    γ∈Reals&&c>0&&x>0,
    ComplexityFunction->(
     LeafCount[#1]+Count[#1,x,All]&
    )]&/@
   ExpandAll[f2[x]],
  x^_
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f1[x_] := (2/x) (c/x)^(\[Gamma] - 1);
f2[x_] := 1 - 2/x (1 + f1[x] + f1[x]^(-\[Theta]))

f = Collect[f2[x], x];
```

What if anything do you know about the sign of `c` and/or `x`?

```
ReplacePart[
  Join[{
    {Assumptions, FullSimplify}, {None, FullSimplify@f}},
   {#, FullSimplify[f, #]} & /@
    Join[
     {c > 0, x > 0, c < 0, x < 0},
     Tuples[{{c > 0, c < 0}, {x > 0, x < 0}}]]],
  {{-1, -1} -> SpanFromAbove,
   {6, -1} -> SpanFromAbove}] //
 Grid[#, Frame -> All,
   Alignment -> {Center, Center}] &
```

[image]